# MVC Display Template not showing

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a model called ComplaintModel:

```
public class ComplaintModel
{
    private Data.MTAEntities db = new MTAEntities();
    public IEnumerable<Complaint> Complaints { get; set; }
    public void GetAllComplaints()
    {
        var complaints = (from c in db.tbComplaints
                          orderby c.CreateDateTime descending
                          select
                              new Complaint()
                                  {
                                      Comment = c.Complaint,
                                      ComplaintID = c.ComplaintID,
                                      CreateDateTime = c.CreateDateTime
                                  });

        Complaints = complaints;
    }
```

On my index page I have the following code:

```
<% Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.Complaints, "Complaint"); %>
```

I am pretty much passing an IEnumerable object to my Display Template. In my display template:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IEnumerable<MTA.Models.Entities.Complaint>>" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="MTA.Models.Entities" %>
<% foreach (Complaint complaint in Model)
   {
%>
<div id="complaint">
    <%:complaint.Comment%>
</div>

<%
   }%>
```

I definitely have one Complaint class in my collection, for some reason it is not displaying. Am I missing something? I also don't get any errors which makes it harder to figure out what I am doing wrong. Only thing I can think of its being lost before it gets to my Display Template somehow?

Thank you!

EDITS:

The exact path to the user control is:    ~/Views/Home/DisplayTemplates/Complaint.ascx

The controller method call:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new MTA.Models.ComplaintModel();
    model.GetAllComplaints();
    ViewData["model"] = model;
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: what is the exact path to `Complaint.ascx`?

Comment: Can you post your controller action method for this view?

Comment: Thanks for responding, I have updated the original question with the additional information that was requested. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

How about this ?  (use ComplaintModel instead)

```
 <%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MTA.Models.Entities.ComplaintModel>" %>
 <%@ Import Namespace="MTA.Models.Entities" %>
 <% foreach (Complaint complaint in Model.Complaints)
 {
 %>
 <div id="complaint">
     <%:complaint.Comment%>
 </div>

 <%}%>
```